# MapStruct set List as field

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I'm using Map Struct with Lombok for mapping DTO and Entity back and forth but occurred on a case:

```
@Mapper(uses = {RoleMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {

    UserDto userToUserDto(User user);

    default User signUpRequestDtoToUser(SignUpRequestDto dto) {
        return User.builder()
                .roles(dto.roleIds.stream().map(id -> Role.builder().id(id).build()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .username(dto.getUsername())
                .password(dto.getPassword())
                .isEnabled(dto.getIsEnabled())
                .build();
    }

    default UserFilter toUserFilter(UserFilterDto dto) {
        return UserFilter.builder()
                .isEnabled(dto.getIsEnabled())
                .username(dto.getUsername())
                .roles(
                        Objects.nonNull(dto.getRoleIds())
                                ? dto.getRoleIds().stream().map(id -> Role.builder().id(id).build()).collect(Collectors.toList())
                                : Collections.emptyList())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Into other cases, I'm using annotation like this: `@Mapping(target = "advisor.id", source = "advisorId")` for create objects from `id`. It's work where parent contains one instance. But `User` and `UserFilter` has `List<Role>` as field.

How to replace the `default` method with annotation?

Comment: What's the importance of Lombok here? Isn't this just a `@Mapper` question?

Comment: @Bohemian, not a big just for the record Lombok is used in the project.

Comment: Best to remove all references to Lombok then, as it is irrelevant and distracts from the actual problem. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in your example, I assume you can use annotations in this case as well: just create a method to map between `RoleId` and `Role` and Mapstruct will implement this method and call it method automatically when trying to map the collections of those models:

```
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
Role mapRoleIdToRole(RoleId roleId);
```